# How to instantiate static class in dynamically loaded library

Tags: c++, dynamic, dll, plugins, shared

I am using a factory-based compile-time plugin system that I'd like to move to be more dynamic.
At the moment it's based around static templatized registrar classes, where the constructor registers the class with the factory.
e.g.

```cpp
template <class T>
SingleModuleRegistrar<T>::SingleModuleRegistrar(ModuleDesc description={ T::factoryName(), T::category }) : _name(description.moduleName)
{
    ModuleFactory& factory = ModuleFactory::Instance();
    factory.Register(this, description);
}
```

and then in a header for a `DefaultPlugin` class

```
static SingleModuleRegistrar<DefaultPlugin> DefaultPluginRegistrar;
```

When this is built in a static library, the `DefaultPlugin` is registered with the factory and available for use.
Now I want to move the static lib to a dll so I can dynamically add new plugins to the factory.
I can load the dll no problem, but the static variable doesn't seem to get instatiated. would you expect that, and if not, how can I trigger instantiation of the static `DefaultPluginRegistrar`?

I can think of a few workarounds, e.g. add a function to register the plugins in a library and call that, but thought if I can keep things as close as possible to the original code that would be great.
Plus, I'd like to understand what is going on with the static variable instantiation during loading.

EDIT:
I think I should add some more detail about the structure. Currently the `DefaultPlugin` registration is in a header in a library that is statically linked into the .dll. It is also in a namespace.

```cpp
MyPlugin.dll
|_ MyStaticLibrary.lib
   |_DefaultPlugin.h
     SomeNamespace {
     class DefaultPlugin : public IPlugin
     {
     public: 
        DefaultPlugin();
        //etc. 
     };

     // registration
     static SingleModuleRegistrar<DefaultPlugin> DefaultPluginRegistrar;

     }
|_ SomeOtherStaticLibrary.lib
```

I've also tried removing the static declaration and exporting the symbol, to no avail

```cpp
__declspec(dllexport) SingleModuleRegistrar<DefaultPlugin> DefaultPluginRegistrar;
```

Comment: What compiler/toolset are you using? IIRC, the runtime support in the DLL should handle initialization of global variables (on the DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH message, I think).

Comment: I’m using visual studio at the moment  but will also need to be able to do this on Linux/gcc

Comment: My guess would be, the DLL gets its own copy of the `ModuleFactory` "singleton" and registers with that - not with the copy that the EXE looks at. Print or otherwise dump `&ModuleFactory::Instance()` in the EXE and the DLL - I suspect you'll see two different addresses.

Comment: That's not it unfortunately.. I'd moved the `ModuleFactory` into a .dll specifically to stop this happening through static linking.
The constructor for `DefaultPlugin` is never called.

Comment: Bit of a red herring above, the constructor of `DefaultPlugin` is not supposed to be called during registration :-D
The registration is not happening either but thought I should clear that up. 

I am seeing that a test plugin *will* register itself if it is in a header that is in the .dll project itself, rather than one of the libs it links in.

Comment: ah holy carp I think I have in my haste to separate out components into libraries, neglected to include the headers from the static libs in my dll...
just confirming now but this looks quite likely to be the cause

Answer (score 0):

OK: super-facepalm time.
I had been reorganizing my code structure into such nice separated libraries that I hadn't actually included the headers containing my static plugin declarations anywhere in the dll code!

I'll leave this question up though, as I found this was quite an unusual configuration to have and it might help someone just to know that it can work.

It might also be helpful to note that in the MS runtime, the static is initialised inside `_initterm` in `initterm.cpp`, from `dll_main_crt_process_attach`.